# Почему заказ придет без товара?

Tags: php, opencart

всем доброго времени суток

1) почему заказ придет без товара?
при этом письмо без товара редко придет-обычно все норм, я у себя тестировал бага нет

opencart Version 2.3.0.2 (trs-2.3.0.0)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопросы:

l. в чем проблема ? сталкивались ли с подобной ошибкой?

ll. если не сталкивались-то какие идеи ? что тут м.б не так? где посмотреть баг? конкретный путь...

﻿

2) при переходе в админке на странице модификаторы-страница долго загружается и в конце такая ошибка -фото 2

поменял версию php на хостинге с 7,1 на 7,2 и на 5,6 -не помог

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос:

как исправить?

заранее благодарю)

Comment: Как-то мало информации. Вы в log файл загялдывали?

Comment: Не описание проблемы, а сумбур какой-то. 
Может товар добавленный в заказ был удален из каталога?

Comment: @ ShevtsovEugene нет товар не был удален

Comment: @LevBazdyrev а где именнно смотреть? на хостинге ли в самом админке есть

Comment: @azizjon в админке его точно нету, смотреть надо на хостинге, только в этом случае он может лежать где угодно, надо уточнять у Вашего хостинг провайдера